# How to portably allocate space for a particular member of a union embedded in a struct

Tags: c, struct, unions, c11, offsetof

Consider the following type in C11, where MyType1 and MyType2 are previously declared types:

```
typedef struct {
  int tag;
  union {
    MyType1 type1;
    MyType2 type2;
  }
} MyStruct;
```

I'd like to allocate enough memory using `malloc` to hold the `tag` attribute and `type1`. Can this be done in a portable way? I guess, `sizeof(tag) + sizeof(type1)` may not work due to alignment issues.

Can I calculate the offset of type1 from the beginning of the structure in a portable way?

Comment: If you need `struct { int tag; MyType1 type1; }` why don't you explicitly define it? It's unclear what you need this, for but it smells like something that will probably break strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @user694733: I want to use pointers to MyStruct. Depending on the tag field, I need type1 or type2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`offsetof()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/offsetof), and since that will include both the size of `tag` and any padding, it's enough to then add the size of `type1`:

```
void *mys = malloc(offsetof(MyStruct, type1) + sizeof (MyType1));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I calculate the offset of type1 from the beginning of the
>   structure in a portable way?

You can probably use `offsetof` from `stddef.h` for this.

```
printf("Offset of type1 in the struct: %zu\n", offsetof(MyStruct, type1));
```

---

Side note: this works because you are using an "*anonymous union*". If you were to say `union { ... } u;` `type1` wouldn't be a member of `MyStruct`.